# How can I make this cover look like a book?

Tags: css

I liked this book design in iBooks and have been wondering can it be easily made with css?

[image: Hardcover]

Original photo

[image: Original photo]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

have you tried gradients and shadows ?

```css
.cover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(60, 13, 20) 3px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 5px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 7px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 10px, transparent 12px, transparent 16px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 17px, transparent 22px), url(https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51pnouuPO5L.jpg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px black, inset -1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 389px;
  height: 500px;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div title=" Don't make me think " class="cover"></div>
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you for your time, terrific!

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be pretty easily done with gradients in CSS. Here's a (very rough) example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6yok9c4w/

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
</div>
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51pnouuPO5L.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 2%, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 3%, rgba(247,254,255,.5) 5%, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 7%, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 13%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
}
img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I used this tool to generate the gradient: https://cssgradient.io/

With more effort and tweaking, I think you can get really close to the original.